# IIS 7.5 returning 500 error on first request (application starts/recycles)

Tags: iis, web, iis-7.5

I'm hosting a simple html file in IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008R2. I've assigned the site a default application pool with No Managed Code. There is nothing more in the folder other than the index.html file and a css file and I haven't changed any other setting within IIS.

On the first request and after every site restart of the site a 500 Internal Error is returned. The following error in the HTTPERR log seems to be the cause:

```
2014-07-04 etc .......- - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
```

On subsequent requests the page loads fine, no problems. Why is this error being thrown on first request and how can I fix this? It doesn't seem to be related to the application pool as it doesn't happen when I recycle it, only when I stop and restart the site.